# loggedfs on mac with osxfuse stuck

Tags: c++, linux, macos, fuse, osxfuse

I would like to log every syscall of a specified directory and I've found this repository https://github.com/rflament/loggedfs

It creates a virtual filesystem with fuse and log everything in it, just like I want.

I tried to port it on mac but it uses a "trick" that doesn't works on osx. The `lstat` is stuck 10s and crash.

I would like to understand why ?

This is a main part of my code :

```
//  g++ -Wall main.cpp `pkg-config fuse --cflags --libs` -o hello

#define FUSE_USE_VERSION 26

#include <fuse.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static char *path;
static int  savefd;

static int getattr(const char *path, struct stat *stbuf)
{
    int res;
    char rPath[1024];

    strcpy(rPath, "."); strcat(rPath, path);

    res = lstat(rPath, stbuf); // Mac stuck here
    return (res == -1 ? -errno : 0); 
}

static void* loggedFS_init(struct fuse_conn_info* info)
{
     fchdir(savefd); close(savefd); return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct fuse_operations oper;

    bzero(&oper, sizeof(fuse_operations));
    oper.init       = loggedFS_init;
    oper.getattr    = getattr;

    path = strdup(argv[argc - 1]);
    printf("chdir to %s\n", path);
    chdir(path);
    savefd = open(".", 0); 

    return fuse_main(argc, argv, &oper, NULL);
}
```

Comment: is rPath contains path to mounted drive?
Don't sure that i understood you problem, but you shouldn't do any file operation in drive from fuse callback - it will lead to deadlock

Answer (score 0):

I had a very close look at LoggedFS and tested it for POSIX compliance using [pjdfstest](https://github.com/pjd/pjdfstest), resulting in [3 issues (or groups of issues)](https://github.com/rflament/loggedfs/issues/created_by/s-m-e). I ended up [re-implementing it in Python](https://github.com/pleiszenburg/loggedfs-python), fully POSIX compliant. I have not tested it on OS X yet, so I'd be happy to receive some feedback ;)

The "trick" you are mentioning could be the root cause of your issue, although I am not entirely sure. It causes a fundamental problem by adding another character to the path, which leads to issues when the length of `path` gets close to PATH_MAX. `libfuse` already passes paths with a leading `/` into FUSE operations. The additional `.` plus the "misleading" `/` (root of the mounted filesystem, not the "global" root folder) are two characters "too many", effectively reducing the maximum allowed path length to PATH_MAX minus 2. I explored options of altering PATH_MAX and informing user land software about a smaller PATH_MAX, which [turned out to be impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48074205/1672565).

There is a way around, however. Do not close the file descriptor `savefd` in the `init` routine. Keep it open and instead close it in the [`destroy` routine](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/fuse-2.9.7/include/fuse.h#L334), which will be called by FUSE when the filesystem is unmounted. You can actually use `savefd` for specifying paths relative to it. You can then use `fstatat` ([Linux](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstatat), [OS X / BSD](https://gist.github.com/Birch-san/ebca41072b8ade2be0bfbc18b110fb94)) instead of `lstat`. Its prototype looks like this:

```
int fstatat(int dirfd, const char *pathname, struct stat *buf,
        int flags);
```

You have to pass `savefd` into `dirfd` and remove the leading `/` from the content of `path` before passing it into `pathname`.